# Error: The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this on windows https://github.com/brian-yang/table-parser-opencv

It says I should run it as follows:  `python main.py <filepath>`

When I try to run it like this:

```
python main.py <C:\Users\blabla\files\filename.jpg>
```

It gives that error

I also tried like this:

```
python main.py <'C:\Users\blabla\files\filename.jpg'>
```

and like this:

```
python main.py <"C:\Users\blabla\files\filename.jpg">
```

and like this:

```
python main.py <r"C:\Users\blabla\files\filename.jpg">
```

and like this:

```
python main.py <r'C:\Users\blabla\files\filename.jpg'>
```

I also tried it with a pdf.

and it still gives the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Can anyone offer any advice? I tried in python interpreter and that seemed to be wrong as well, considering the line of code is already calling python.

Comment: What are the brackets (`<` and `>`) there for?

Comment: The angle brackets are just there to indicate that `filepath` is something you need to fill in.  You absolutely do not want to include them in the actual command you type.

Comment: @ScottHunter - Unfortunately, that is exactly what the documentation suggests.

Comment: If the instructions said `run: python main.py filepath` then people would literally run `python main.py filepath` with the word filepath, which would be wrong. So they use the placeholder `<filepath>` to indicate the variable thing that *you* supply.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny only for people who aren't accustomed to how technical documentation for command line tools is conventionally written.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, and everything to do with whatever command interpreter you are using to run Python.

Comment: @chepner: This has nothing to do with the command interpreter, and everything to do with standard documentation conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

`python main.py C:\Users\blabla\files\filename.jpg`

It is basically a way of passing the parameters using command line

Comment: Off-topic questions should be closed, not answered. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Well that worked but now for some reason it's not reading it as a jpg, thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you’re trying to run a Python script and pass a file path as an argument. In Python, command-line arguments are passed after the script name and are separated by spaces. Here’s the corrected syntax:

python main.py "C:\Users\blabla\files\filename.jpg"

Please note that in Windows, paths use backslashes (), but in Python, a backslash is an escape character. To include a literal backslash, you need to escape it by using two backslashes (\). Also, if your path contains spaces, you should enclose it in quotes.